# Change address format programmatically in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I need to programmatically (using class mediator), set the format of outgoing message. I know that I can do it in xml by setting the format property of an address, e.g.

```
<address uri="http://localhost/servicetest/test.svc/soap" format="soap11">
```

but I need to set it programmatically, because I'm in WSO2 Api Manager, so I can't modify api configurations that are automatically generated.

I also know that I can set it in api publisher using advanced configuration, but I need to set it at runtime on the basis of some condition.

How can I change this property at runtime?

**UPDATE**

if i set axis2 property to text/xml as suggested by Jean-Michel the message is sent as xml but not soap, moreover some numbers appear befor and after the sent xml:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "POST http://localhost/servicetest/test.svc/rest/test1/test2 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_SUBSCRIBER: admin@applicationprovider.it[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_VERSION: rest[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_PUBLISHER: admin@serviceprovider.it[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_APPLICATION_ID: 1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,873] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_NAME: rest[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_APPLICATION_NAME: DefaultApplication[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Host: localhost:80[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "15[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<Prop1>prova1</Prop1>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 12:36:28,874] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I manage to obtain a rest to soap programmatically setting messageType in conjunction with setDoingREST:

```
((Axis2MessageContext) msgCtx).getAxis2MessageContext().setDoingREST(false);
((Axis2MessageContext) msgCtx).getAxis2MessageContext().setProperty("messageType","text/xml");
```

but i still get some weird output...

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "POST http://localhost/servicetest/test.svc/rest/test1/test2 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_SUBSCRIBER: admin@applicationprovider.it[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_VERSION: rest2[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_PUBLISHER: admin@serviceprovider.it[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_APPLICATION_ID: 1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_API_NAME: rest[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "PD_APPLICATION_NAME: DefaultApplication[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Host: localhost:80[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "b5[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><Prop1>prova1</Prop1></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-04-14 16:07:04,438] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 ESB, you can define a property named "**messageType**" on scope "**axis2**". If you want to send a **soap11** message, set it's value to "**text/xml**" and if you want to send a **soap12** message, set it's value to "**application/soap+xml**"